# pandas version impact on tables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a html file with tables.(wikipedia links)
I am trying to access the tables using pandas.

My code is :

```
dfs=pd.read_html(url1)
for i in range(0,5):
    print(dfs[i])
```

This works in pandas version 0.23.0

but the same does not work on 0.23.4 version.
I get the error

```
    dfs=pd.read_html(url1)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 987, in read_html
    displayed_only=displayed_only)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 815, in _parse
    raise_with_traceback(retained)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 797, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 213, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 471, in _parse_tables
    raise ValueError('No tables found')
ValueError: No tables found
```

how to resolve this

Comment: Could be a bug. Might want to report it to them

Comment: I downgraded the panda version now same Error I am seeing, should be some thing else

Comment: Can you update the question with an example of the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Use beautiful soap with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bicycle-sharing_systems")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser') 
table = soup.find_all('table')[0] 
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
```

This syntax is using default html.parser. You can use one of alternative parser (first you need to install them with pip):

- lxml
- lxml-xml / xml
- html5lib

Comment: Thank you can you help me in fixing with pandas. I dont want to use beautiful soup

Comment: I am getting the following error: No handlers could be found for logger "bs4.dammit"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract1.py", line 8, in <module>
    table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: can you share your wikipedia link so I will test on that one